# novell certificate file missing after restart

Tags: certificate, sles, novell, groupwise

Every time I restart my Novell Groupwise on Suse Open Enterprise server the root certificate goes missing. Thats why ldap is not starting and so the other services are not working. After repairing the cert on the second server via imanager everything works fine, until the next restart.
This only happens on the first server. The second restarts without problems.

Answer (score 0):

So this is your eDirectory certificate, used for LDAP over SSL.

Is the certificate object disappearing from the directory, or is the setting in the LDAP Server object loosing its reference to the certificate object?

One of the new features in eDirectory 8.8 SP3 I think was that on every ndsd restart, the certificates are validated and recreated if needed.  Now it should regenerate the certificate, however, if it is deleting and recreating the certificate instead then the DN syntax attribute reference goes poof.

I would consider generating a fresh new cert to use for LDAP SSL on this server since it seems like something may be wrong with the current object, causing it to be deleted and recreated instead of just getting a cert private key added.